# How to detect triangle bitmap collisions android?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, bitmap, geometry

I'm making an Android game and I'm having some problems with bitmap collision detection. The problem is that one of the bitmaps is a triangle and the second one is a rectangle. I don't know how to detect collision between them because now I use this code:

```
if(policeY<((canvas.getHeight()/20)+eye.getHeight()) && (policeY+police.getHeight())>(canvas.getHeight()/20)){
            if((policeX+police.getWidth())>triangleLeft && policeX<(triangleLeft+eye.getWidth())){
                //collision
                play = false;
            }else if((policeX+police.getWidth())<triangleLeft && policeX>(triangleLeft+eye.getWidth())){
                //collision
                play = false;
            }

        }
```

However, this code handles both of them as rectangles and this causes collision even when triangle isn't even touching rectangle.

[Like in this picture the circled area is considered as a collision](http://s29.postimg.org/uzj5rftpz/stack.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd set up the problem as an intersection problem. Define the edges of the triangles as lines then use the [line-line intersection](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&ei=D5vWVM7NFdDsoASwx4HACw&url=http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line%25E2%2580%2593line_intersection&ved=0CBwQFjAA&usg=AFQjCNHWoOADaW6L6qlpgSe1B47lioO7pg&sig2=BY627ahhDvubCgzu7JU1pw) formula with the edges of the rectangle. Then check whether this point is on the edge of the rectangle or if it is outside the rectangle.